# Ionic.Zip.Unity.dll ZlibException on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, build, zip

I'm developing a mobile game for Android and iOS using Unity.
In my game I need to download a compressed file and extract it.

In order to manage compression and decompression, I'm using Ionic.Zip.Unity (you can found that library at https://github.com/r2d2rigo/dotnetzip-for-unity).
Ionic.Zip is a stripped down version of DotNetZip library, that should work with Android and iOS.

So, my code is:

```
string fileStr = "*************";
byte[] fileData = Convert.FromBase64String(fileStr);

MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);

ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(fileStream);
foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
{
     MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

     zipEntry.Extract(memoryStream);

     memoryStream.position = 0;
     StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
     string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

     Debug.Log("String decoded: " + str);
}
```

*fileStr contains the encrypted string.

This code works fine on Editor with all platforms (Android, PC, iOS).
If I build the apk for Android, it works.
The problem is with the iOS build. The code compile but runtime I have this exception:

ZlibException
inflating: rc=323508496 msg=

I have tried to remove .dll and add the source code to the project and it works. How is it possibile?

I really need help cause I finish my ideas.

Thank you all.

Comment: Which Unity and Xcode versions do you use? I think I'm facing the same problem. Maybe I'll have a fix in 1-2 hours, I hope ;)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue using `BestHTTP` (which also uses `Zlib` under the hood). It took me almost two days now, to find out that it is definitely related to specific `Unity` and `Xcode` versions, not working together correctly.

**The issue occures on `Unity 5.5.0f3` and `Unity 5.6.0f1`, using `Xcode 8.3` but it doesn't occur using `Xcode 8.2.1`.**

I'll do further investigation and check if it's working with a newer Unity version. And keep you updated.

---

#### Update:

Seems to be a bug in Unity which should be resolved in the near future.

> Fix in review

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-xcode-ios-xcode-3-throw-error-when-played-xcode-8-dot-2-1-does-not

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm working on:

- Unity 5.3.1p4
- XCode 8.3.1.

So the only fix is update XCode to a previous version?

Comment: It seems like. Or upgrading Unity once they've released the fix.

Comment: I have downgraded XCode to 8.2.1 and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear! Would be nice if you would accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with new xcode 8.3.x, the problem is with new Xcode and the way how LLVM stripping the unused code. It could be a bug from xcode or the new way how it does it. One thing you can try is to set Dead Code Stripping flag in Build Setting to NO

Answer (score 0):

```
use this package --> https://github.com/tsubaki/UnityZip 

To-do's for UniZip for Unity & XCode:

add "PluginsCode > iOS > ZipArchive" files & folder to Unity project Assets\Plugins\ After that copy from package UnityZip:>Asset>Plugins (folders, files) & add to your project : "Assets/Plugins/IOS" Alterations for UniZip for iOS successful build:

If package is newly imported after above setup: (1) Open "ZipArchive.mm" file and REMOVE:  -line 270[dc release]  -line 271[gregorian release]  -line 327[comp release]  -line 328[gregorian release]  -line 40[super delloc]

(2) Open "UnityZipFile.mm" file and REMOVE:

-line 32[zip release]`enter code here`
-line 35[list release]
-line 59[zip release]

-Before Build in XCode select "unity framework" from "unity iPhone" and go to "build settings>other>flags" add -lz symbol.
```